# Querying a Pandas DataFrame: How can I use a string variable that has been previously defined to filter?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas Dataframe with a column named "Colors". I am trying to query the table using *pd.query* so that I only get the lines that have **red** as a color by using a variable that I pre-defined:

```
filtered_color = "red"
```

This works:

```
df.query('Colors == ["red"]')
```

However, when I try to reference my variable:

```
df.query('Colors == filtered_color')
```

I get an error:

```
UndefinedVariableError: name 'filtered_color' is not defined
```

How can I reference the variable inside of the query?

Comment: ```df.query('Colors == {}'.format(filtered_color))```, this replaces value of `filtered_color` instead of string `filtered_color`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `@` symbol to reference variables in queries.

Comment: Related question: what's the logic of this syntax? Is it exclusive to the query function of pandas?

Comment: Yes, it is specific to the query syntax. Don't use it with other pandas operations. As for its origins, most database systems I've worked with use @ to designate variables, so my guess is that pandas borrowed that familiar syntax.